# How to get missing values in date range?

Tags: sql, date, range, between

I have table with following structure:

[image]

And I'm trying to get grouped values between two dates, problem is, that i would like to have also retuned rows for dates which are not in select, for example i have range for

```
WHERE m.date BETWEEN "2014-09-02" AND "2014-09-10"
```

But for example in date 2014-09-06 is no related row in table, so in result should be

```
 2014-09-06| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

How can i do it please? (if is it possible with SQLLite database).

**Here is the query which i'm using:**

```
  SELECT substr(m.date, 1, 10) as my_date, COUNT(m.ID) AS 'NUMBER_OF_ALL_CALLS',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dialed_calls subq WHERE subq.call_result = 'DONE'
    AND substr(m.date, 1, 10) = substr(subq.DATE, 1, 10)) as 'RESULT_DONE',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dialed_calls subq WHERE subq.call_result = 'NOT_INTERESTED' 
    AND substr(m.date, 1, 10) = substr(subq.DATE, 1, 10)) as 'RESULT_NOT_INTERESTED',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dialed_calls subq WHERE subq.call_result = 'NO_APPOINTMENT'
    AND substr(m.date, 1, 10) = substr(subq.DATE, 1, 10)) as 'RESULT_NO_APP'
    FROM dialed_calls m
    WHERE m.date BETWEEN "2014-09-02" AND "2014-09-05"
    GROUP BY my_date
```

Many thanks for any help.

**Table structure:**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE dialed_calls(Id integer PRIMARY KEY,
'date' datetime,
'called_number' VARCHAR(45),
'call_result' VARCHAR(45),
'call_duration' INT,
'synced' BOOL);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(1,'2014-09-02 15:54:34+0200',
'800123456', 'NOT_INTERESTED', 10, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(2,'2014-09-02 15:56:30+0200',
'800123456', 'NO_APPOINTMENT', 10, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(3,'2014-09-02 16:01:49+0200',
'800123456', 'DONE', 9, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(4,'2014-09-02 16:03:03+0200',
'800123456', 'NO_APPOINTMENT', 69, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(5,'2014-09-02 18:09:34+0200',
'800123456', 'NO_APPOINTMENT', 3, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(6,'2014-09-02 18:54:02+0200',
'123456789', 'NO_APPOINTMENT', 89, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(7,'2014-09-02 18:55:25+0200',
'123456789', 'NOT_INTERESTED', 89, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(8,'2014-09-03 18:36:58+0200',
'123456789', 'DONE', 185, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(9,'2014-09-04 18:36:58+0200',
'123456789', 'DONE', 185, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(10,'2014-09-05 18:36:58+0200',
'123456789', 'DONE', 185, 0);
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  d.date AS DATE, 
  IFNULL(NUMBER_OF_ALL_CALLS, 0) AS NUMBER_OF_ALL_CALLS, 
  IFNULL(RESULT_DONE, 0) AS RESULT_DONE, 
  IFNULL(RESULT_NOT_INTERESTED, 0) AS RESULT_NOT_INTERESTED, 
  IFNULL(RESULT_NO_APP, 0) AS RESULT_NO_APP
FROM 
 (SELECT DATE('1970-01-01', '+' || (t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) || ' days') date FROM
 (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
 (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
 (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
 (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
 (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4) d
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT substr(m.date, 1, 10) as my_date, COUNT(m.ID) AS 'NUMBER_OF_ALL_CALLS',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dialed_calls subq WHERE subq.call_result = 'DONE'
    AND substr(m.date, 1, 10) = substr(subq.DATE, 1, 10)) as 'RESULT_DONE',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dialed_calls subq WHERE subq.call_result = 'NOT_INTERESTED' 
    AND substr(m.date, 1, 10) = substr(subq.DATE, 1, 10)) as 'RESULT_NOT_INTERESTED',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dialed_calls subq WHERE subq.call_result = 'NO_APPOINTMENT'
    AND substr(m.date, 1, 10) = substr(subq.DATE, 1, 10)) as 'RESULT_NO_APP'
    FROM dialed_calls m
    GROUP BY my_date
) t
ON d.date = t.my_date
WHERE d.date BETWEEN '2014-09-02' AND '2014-09-10'
ORDER BY d.date;
```

Above query will first the retrieve the dates between the specified date range and later will join the retrieved values with your table.

Comment: Thanks very much, but is it quite slow query (i need it for mobile app). Is any way to speed it? Fxp: 1970-01-01 change to nearest date to today?

Comment: 1970-01-01 is the start date. If you want to make it start from a more current date, you can change that value. You can also optimize your query for a better response time.

Comment: What you can recommend to optimize on this query?

Comment: For example instead of your inner queries, you can write such query: `SELECT substr(m.date, 1, 10) as my_date, COUNT(m.ID) AS 'NUMBER_OF_ALL_CALLS',
    call_result AS 'CALL_RESULT'
    FROM dialed_calls m
    WHERE m.date BETWEEN "2014-09-02" AND "2014-09-05"
    GROUP BY my_date, call_result;` but this query will return `call_result` values vertically. Later you can transform the data in your application.

Comment: Or else you can try this query: `SELECT substr(m.date, 1, 10) as my_date,
  SUM(1) AS 'NUMBER_OF_ALL_CALLS',
  SUM(CASE WHEN call_result = 'DONE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'RESULT_DONE',
  SUM(CASE WHEN call_result = 'NOT_INTERESTED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'RESULT_NOT_INTERESTED',
  SUM(CASE WHEN call_result = 'NO_APPOINTMENT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'RESULT_NO_APP'
    FROM dialed_calls m
    WHERE m.date BETWEEN "2014-09-02" AND "2014-09-05"
    GROUP BY my_date`

Answer (score 1):

This is a good case for joining to a Calendar table.

http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html
Note this is a SQL server link, but you can adapt this to SQLlite.

You could do your calculations, and then right join the results to the calendar table, so that the dates appear with NULL values. Or you could COALESCE() the nulls to something that makes more sense, like 0.

Comment: Hello, thanks but it seems to be a quite complex solution. I'm looking for something which can be used by simple SQL query.

Comment: It makes the queries much *simpler*! If JOINs are too hard, I would suggest taking the time to properly learn SQL. @oardic's solution essentially creates that calendar table *every* time you run you query. Why not just materialize it??

Answer (score 0):

to get intermediate dates as the query result you need a table with all the dates in the range.
in some rdbms you can populate a temporary table to join with.
you will have to compare the date part only (without time).

be careful with your between because the second date has time 00:00:00 and maybe it's not what you meant.